# Can I define breakpoint specific spacing to a custom Material-ui theme?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, breakpoints

I am working through making my Material-ui + React dashboard responsively styled to better display on different screen sizes, My custom theme includes a `spacing` setting of `8`:

```
import { createMuiTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

// https://material-ui.com/customization/themes/
export default createMuiTheme({
  spacing: 8
});
```

A large amount of my components then include a custom stylesheet, which all reference the custom theme, for example:

```
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

export default makeStyles(theme => ({
  queryContainer: {
    padding: theme.spacing(3),
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.common.white,
    color: theme.palette.common.white,
    borderBottom: theme.border.default
  }
}));
```

This then styles the `queryContainer` component with a `padding` attribute set to `24px`.

**On the custom theme I am hoping to be able to define a different Spacing value for each different Breakpoint.** By default Material-ui includes the following breakpoints:

```
xs: 0
sm: 600
md: 960
lg: 1280
xl: 1920
```

For example on screens that fall under `md` I would like Spacing to be set as 6, this would save me from having to customise the `spacing` on each component using media queries, and the `queryContainer` component would then have its `padding` attribute set to `18px` at this specific screen size.

Does Material-ui have any way to define a different `spacing` value for each Breakpoint? I haven't seen any examples of this on the Material-ui documentation. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass a function to the createTheme spacing field as mentined in the [docs](https://material-ui.com/customization/spacing/#spacing):

```
function setSpacing(factor) {
    const width = window.innerWidth;
    if (width > 600) {
          return 8 * factor;
    } else {
          return 6 * factor;
    }
}
```

Now if you call:

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
    spacing: setSpacing
});
```

The spacing value will be evaluated on every access within makeStyles/createStyles and returns a different value for different screen sizes. You should expand the setSpacing function to fit your needs, but the factors (8,6) correspond with what you mentioned above for spacing(3) should return 24/18 for different screen sizes.
Hope this helps. Happy coding.

Comment: Thanks for your help @Domino987 - Your answer solved my problem!